# How to get multiple outputs of a function in a vector?

Tags: matlab, function, vector, output

Say I have a function whose outputs are two reals a and b

```
[a,b]=function(c)
```

I'd like to get all the outputs in a vector v.
v=function(c) doesn't do what I want, v is 'a' only.
Of course here I could do v=[a,b].
But the function in question is ind2sub for a N-D array so it gives n outputs that I'd like to have in a vector directly.

Is there a way to do it? 
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cell array and [a comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) like so:

```
X = cell(N, 1);
[X{:}] = function(C);
```

The syntax `X{:}` is in fact expanded to `[X{1}, X{2}, ...]`, which provides a valid sink for your function. As a result, each output variable will be stored in a different cell in `X`.

If each output variable is a scalar, you can flatten out the cell array into a vector by using  yet another comma-separated list expansion:

```
v = [X{:}];
```

Comment: Thanks! Comma-separated lists help a lot!

Comment: Or you could use cell2mat at the end. Or you could write a function that will do it for you. The nice thing about a tool like MATLAB is you can customize it to do what you like in this way, adding your own desired functionality as needed.

Comment: @woodchips in my experience, Mathematica, R and xlisp-stat are all vastly superior to Matlab for customization.  Matlab's syntax is too clunky (e.g. this question is *very* difficult to answer for even very experienced Matlab users).

Comment: @John - and that is why it helps to write a helper function, writing it only once, rather than having to remember the trick. I'll agree, in this case, the syntax is not trivial, but overall, I prefer MATLAB to some of the others you mention. THis is just personal preference of course, and it will vary for every person.

Comment: @JuliaR Remember to accept the answers if they have worked for you!