# Save multivariable output from function to vector?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a function that returns multiple values:

```
function [a,b,c] = f()
  a = 1; b = 2; c = 3;
end
```

How to I save the output into a vector without having to create intermediate variables? Example shown below:

```
> z = zeros(1,3);
> [a,b,c] = f();
> z(:) = [a,b,c];
> z
ans =

   1   2   3
```

I don't have to define intermediate variables `a`, `b`, `c`, but only if I define an additional cell array:

```
> ce = cell(1, 3);
> [ce{:}] = f();
> z(:) = cell2mat(ce);
> z
ans =

   1   2   3
```

Is there a better way to go directly from `z(:) = f()`?

Comment: Don't create those variables  in the first place. Just create a single array containing all those variables

Comment: Multiple return values may have different sizes,  how do you want to concatenate them into an array? This syntax is allowed : `[z(1),z(2),z(3)]=f();`

Comment: You can use [varargout](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html) to manage the type and number of output variables. You can find an example in this my [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48671290/4806927).

Comment: These are all good suggestions... but what if I didn't write the function? The `[z(1), z(2), ...] = f()` is likely the most direct solution.