# Checking how function has been called in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a task to write a function that has an optional output argument.

Let's say I have a `function y = fun(a,b)`. From what I understood, depending on whether the user needs the value `y`, it will EITHER calculate `y` OR draw some diagram.

So I think it means that if user calls my function like this: `z = fun(1,2)`, then it calculates `y` and returns it, but if he calls it like this: `fun(3,4);`, then it won't return anything and draw a diagram instead.

**Is there any way to check how my function has been called inside it?** If yes, then how?

Comment: You can use [varargout](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html) to control the number of the output of a function, You can find an [example of how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48671290/4806927) in this my answer to similar question. Of course you have to pass a parameter to the function to be used as a flag to select the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`nargout`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html), that roughly translates to *number of argument to output* (there is also a [`nargin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html) to check the number of input arguments).

However, the function will return the return-value anyway if your just check for `nargin`. You will also need to use [`varargout`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html) (*variable argument output*) to make your function return something only if the output will be assigned to some external variable.

So you just write in your function

```
function varargout = fun()

if nargout % implicit cast to a logical. It is equivalent to nargout > 0
    % return output
    varargout{1} = true; % note that this requires to wrap your output in a cell
else
    % do plotting
end
```

**EDIT:**
It is even not necessary to use `varargout`. If you don't assign a value to a return-variable, it won't appear. So MATLAB can manage a not-assigned return-variable (something I was surprised to learn myself^^). This even works with multiple outputs!

Comment: You don’t need `varargout`, you can simply not assign to the output variable as shown in the other answer. Otherwise, nicely written answer!

Comment: oh that is true. Was this ever since or is it a new feature? I always thought it would be necessary

Comment: This has always been this way, at least since MATLAB 5.3 (1999) when I started using it seriously.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [nargout](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html) here:

```
function y = q61527462(a,b)
    if nargout > 0
        % Calculate y
        y = a + b;
    else
        % Plot
        plot(a,b)
    end
end
```

so when you call the function as:

```
>> y = q61527462(1,2)
```

you get:

```
y =

     3
```

and when you call with:

```
>> q61527462(1,2)
```

you get the plot